# $f_n=2$ or $f_n=1/2$, depending on a fair coin. Is there a nonzero probability that the product of $f_n$'s can get arbitrarily large?

Tags: probability

We repeatedly flip a fair coin. If on the $n$th flip we get Heads, we define $f_n=2$. If Tails, we define $f_n=\frac{1}{2}$.

> Is there a nonzero probability that
>   $\sup_m\prod_{n=1}^mf_n=\infty$?

On one hand, the law of large numbers guarantees that the ratio of $2$'s to $\frac{1}{2}$'s tends to one.

On the other hand, if $m$ is very large it is plausible that $\prod_{n=1}^mf_n$ could be large even when the ratio of $2$'s to $\frac{1}{2}$'s only slightly exceeds one.

Comment: Oops, thanks @KaviRamaMurthy. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be seen as a random walk of the set $\{ 2^k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Indeed :
$$\prod_{n=1}^m f_n = 2^{A}2^{-B}.$$

Where $A$ is the number of times we had $2$ and $B$ the number of $\frac 1 2$ we had out of $m$ tosses.

Hence :

$$\log_2{\prod_{n=1}^m f_n}=A-B.$$

$X=A-B$ then defines a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, and it is symmetric since the coin is fair.
A symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ is known to be recurrent. Hence the $\sup$ of $A-B$ will hit $\infty$, so $\prod_{n=1}^m f_n$ will be as high as you want if you toss coins enough (and also as close to $0$ as you want).

To conclude :

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_m\prod_{n=1}^mf_n=\infty\right)=1$$